# Save remaining Json object from http - Body in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

A Go method is supposed to save any JSON object in a MongoDB. In the code, only the ID and not the entire object is saved. How to fix that?

```
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "net/http"
)


//insert the value to mongoDB without any parsing
func InsertObjectToDatabase(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    //call database and collection
    currentDatabase := clients.MongoClientForThisMicroservice.Database("APP_MONGO_DB")
    currentCollection := currentDatabase.Collection("APP_MONGO_DB")

    //convert structured data to bson
    bsonBytes, errBsonConvert := bson.Marshal(json.NewDecoder(request.Body))
    if errBsonConvert != nil {
        ErrorResponse(response, errBsonConvert)
        return
    }

    //write values to database
    _, errInsertDatabase := currentCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), bsonBytes)
    if errInsertDatabase != nil {
        ErrorResponse(response, errInsertDatabase)
        return
    }

    return
}
```

Result in MongoDB

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "611b754fd413ee180f0a3d0a"
}
```

Comment: `InsertOne()` expects a Go value. You don't need to call `bson.Marshal()`. Unmarshal the JSON value from `request.Body`, and pass that to `InsertOne()`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not getting it right now. Would you like to change the code briefly to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a Go value, not a `bson.Marshal()` version.

E.g.:

```golang
var model Model
if err := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(model); err != nil {
        // handle m
}
_, _ = currentCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), model)
```